# Using Conditional Random Fields for Nested named entity recognition

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition

My question is the following.

When we work on Named entity recognition tasks, in most cases the classic LSTM-CRF architecture is used, where the CRF uses the Viterbi decoder and the transition matrix to find the best tag sequence associated to a sentence.

My question is, if a token is now associated to multiple entities and not just one (which is the case of Nested NER), as in the case of Bank of China, where China is a location and Bank of China is an organization. Can the CRF algorithm be adapted for this case? That is, finding more than one possible path in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to the datasets format more than the LSTM-CRF in itself, i.e. you may indeed implement a LSTM-CRF that would recognize nested entities, without depth limitation, but they are rather rare.

Most of the machine learning (including LSTM-CRF) software are learned with a CoNLL (tab separated) dataset format, which is not convenient for unlimited depth nesting. Many dataset and systems implement a fixed depth nesting, using additional columns (more or less one per nesting depth). Software may use separate or joint learning for each depth or use cascading models.